# C++ OOP quiz question

Tags: c++

I'm doing a C++ quiz and I need to say whats wrong in the following code:

```
class Base {
    friend class SubClass;
    int n;
    virtual int getN()
    {
        return n;
    }
};

class SubClass: public Base {
public:
    SubClass() {}
    SubClass(const SubClass& s) {}
};

int main()
{
    SubClass sc;
    if(sc.getN() <= 5)
    {
        int x = sc.getN();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Besides that n is uninitilized and maybe the object should be created through a Base class pointer, what else could be wrong?
When I run it I get this error:

```
 error: 'virtual int Base::getN()' is private
```

Comment: Even considering it's a quiz question, the main mistake in this piece of code is it's completley pointless.

Comment: Try it the other way around: What is the point of this piece of code? It neither does anything defined nor does it represent any valuable concept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As by default every member of a class<sup>1</sup> is `private`, `getN` in the base class is  declared `private`.

Make `getN` public as:

```
class Base {
    friend class SubClass;
    int n;
public: //<--------------------- you forgot this
    virtual int getN()
    {
        return n;
    }
};
```

<sup>1. I mean, a class defined with the keyword `class`. Note that class can be defined with the keyword `struct` and `union` as well, according to the C++ Standard.</sup>

---

EDIT:

If you think because `SubClass` is a friend of `Base`, so it can access private members of `Base` from outside, then that is wrong. `friend` means member functions of `SubClass` can access private members of `Base` class.

However, if you make `main()` friend of `Base`, then your code would work:

```
 class Base {
        friend int main(); //make main() friend of Base
        //...
    };
```

Now from `main()`,  any private members of `Base` can be accessed!

See this demo : http://www.ideone.com/UKkCF

Comment: So that is the problem, getN() should be public. But I am confuse about this, if SubCLass is a friend of Base doesnt he has acces to private members ?

Comment: Or is acceseble only in the derived class, not main , i guess

Comment: @vBx: Make `main()` friend of `Base`, then your code would work. See the edit for the explanation.

Comment: @Nawaz: yes its completly logical that if SubClass its a friend of base, only SubClass can acces private memebers, no one else, stupid mistake from me :)

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler should give you some clues...

```
% g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ test.cpp
test.cpp:1: warning: ‘class Base’ has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
test.cpp:10: warning: ‘class SubClass’ has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Base::Base()’:
test.cpp:1: warning: ‘Base::n’ should be initialized in the member initialization list
test.cpp: In constructor ‘SubClass::SubClass()’:
test.cpp:12: note: synthesized method ‘Base::Base()’ first required here 
test.cpp: In copy constructor ‘SubClass::SubClass(const SubClass&)’:
test.cpp:13: warning: base class ‘class Base’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor
test.cpp: At global scope:
test.cpp:13: warning: unused parameter ‘s’
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4: error: ‘virtual int Base::getN()’ is private
test.cpp:19: error: within this context
test.cpp:4: error: ‘virtual int Base::getN()’ is private
test.cpp:21: error: within this context
test.cpp:21: warning: unused variable ‘x’
```

Comment: There's actually so much wrong conceptually with this code that even those compiler messages won't cover everything. For example: Why is `SubClass` a `friend`?

Comment: Your compiler maybe...my compiler only gives the last 2, i use MinGW

Comment: @LumpN: its a quiz, doesnt a quiz supposed to be like this ? :)

Comment: @LumpN: I only said clues, not answers. This is a [homework] question after all. @vBx: Try turning up your warning levels to get more feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all: `getN` is implicitly `private`, which is the default for classes in C++.

Use

```
class Base {
 // ...

public:
   virtual int getN();
};
```

to make it a publicly accessible member. The facts that `SubClass` is a friend of `Base` and that `getN` is called through an instance of `Subclass` don't matter here - `getN` is simply not accessible from within `main()`, where it is called from. You could make `main` a `friend` of `Base`, however.

Answer (score 2):

the function

```
virtual int getN() { /*...*/ }
```

is private(by default) within your Base class. Since it's not overloaded within you SubClass, it stays private when you call it within your main function.

If you want to make it legal, make it public within the class:

```
public:
    virtual int getN() { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Base {
    friend class SubClass;
    int n;
public:
    virtual int getN()
    {
        return n;
    }
};
```

class members are private as default

Answer (score 0):

you can not access to getN() before make it as public